# Exporting to Excel with Lightswitch

Tags: silverlight, export-to-excel, visual-studio-lightswitch

we started to develop applications with Lightswitch and we are stuck with an exporting problem.

By default, with an "Export to Excel" button you can popup the whole grid in an excel file.

What I need is to programmatically export the active grid with a button click and save it to a presetted path.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can export to excel - this http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/generator may help. However, force them to save it in a location Im not sure you can, unless your silverlight thing is desktop based.

Answer (score 0):

The source code to a LightSwitch extension for Office is available here: [Office Integration Pack](http://officeintegration.codeplex.com/). If the existing functionality doesn't suit yuour requiremebnts, you can modify it to do what you want.